# Como crear una vista en SQL Server eliminando cierta información de algunas columna?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vistas

Buen día, quisiera saber cómo se podría mostrar una vista en SQL eliminando cierta información de algunas columnas como se muestra en el siguiente ejemplo

| IDAlumno | Alumno | Notas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Juan perez | 10 |
|  |  | 9 |
|  |  | 10 |
| 2 | Miguel Lopez | 10 |
|  |  | 8 |
|  |  | 10 |

Comment: No hagas eso. Las vistas y las tablas no tienen un orden determinado. Lo que buscas hacer debe de existir solo en la capa de presentación y no en una vista. ¿Qué pasa si alguien decide ordenar las filas por notas? No sabrás a que alumno pertenece cada una.

Comment: Lo quiero guardar en un store procedure para solo traerlo al lenguaje C# no lo manipulare, solo será para mostrar esa vista e imprimir la información.

Comment: Entonces arregla la vista en c#... sql que devuelva todo. No tenes que hacer esto en SQL.. nunca....

Comment: Es mas.. te lo planteo de otra forma.. sin saber para que es.. como sabria luego c# a quien pertenece la nota 10, si vos le borraste toda la otra informacion??? Las filas siempre deben estar completas.. el que se tiene que preocupar por esto, es quien lo muestra....

Comment: Y con qué criterio elige uno mostrar algo o no? Y si mejor controlas la visibilidad en la presentación?